# Is a plug with a repaired ground prong safe?

Tags: electrical, wiring, safety

my grounded cord lost the ground prong,  I drilled it out and replaced it with a prong which is the same size and length and epoxied it.  It fits precisely in the outlets.  Is it safe?

Comment: How did you bond the new pin to the wire? It doesn't sound safe.  You should replace the entire male plug.

Comment: I call shenanigans.  this can't be real.

Answer (score 10):

No, that's not safe, Epoxy will not make a strong conductive bond to the ground wire in the plug. While the replacement prong may good contact in the outlet, you also need to be sure that it will make good contact to the ground wire in the plug. A simple multimeter test may show that it's connected right now, but the wire and/or replacement prong may shift over time, making the extension cord unsafe due to the lack of a ground connection.

Instead, replace the whole plug with a replacement plug, such as this [Heavy-Duty 3-Wire Replacement Male Electrical Plug](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003URJVPU) (there are many other [varieties](https://www.google.com/search?output=search&tbm=shop&q=replacement+plug+3+prong) or replacement plugs available):

[image]